# how to share state between multi slots and their parents in svelte

Tags: components, state, svelte, slot

I want to create an accordion collapse UI component with svelte, and implement like this:

```
<collapse activeItem="1">
  <collapse-item title="标题1" name="1">代码是写出来给人看的，附带能在机器上运行</collapse-item>
  <collapse-item title="标题2" name="2">代码是写出来给人看的，附带能在机器上运行2</collapse-item>
  <collapse-item title="标题3" name="3">代码是写出来给人看的，附带能在机器上运行3</collapse-item>
</collapse>
```

And look like this:

[image]

When we change the value of collapse's activeItem prop, the collapse-item with the same value of the name props will expand.

But it is really hard for me to make an approach to let the collapse-item know the value of prop activeItem of their parent collapse component.

I can also add an activeItem prop on collapse-item like this:

```
<collapse activeItem="1">
  <collapse-item title="标题1" activItem="1" name="1">代码是写出来给人看的，附带能在机器上运行</collapse-item>
  <collapse-item title="标题2" activItem="1" name="2">代码是写出来给人看的，附带能在机器上运行2</collapse-item>
  <collapse-item title="标题3" activItem="1" name="3">代码是写出来给人看的，附带能在机器上运行3</collapse-item>
</collapse>
```

But this kinds of approach is not so elegant.

I really need some suggestion on this kinds of situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a [`store`](https://svelte.dev/docs#svelte_store) (a store is an object that allows reactive access to a value via a simple store contract) in [`context`](https://svelte.dev/docs#setContext), The context is then available to children of the component (including slotted content).

Comment: Context is really a good suggestion, I haven't use it before, but after read the doc, I know it is what I need, thank you. The UI component may have many in one page, to prevent confict, so I can't use the store

Comment: The store also needs to make activeItem reactive to the children, and I can create the store in the component but not a stand-alone store.js to prevent the confict

Answer (score 0):

Try going to [svelte.dev](https://svelte.dev/examples#auto-subscriptions) and making the editor look like this:

```js
Collapse.svelte:

<script>
    import { active } from './stores.js';
    import Item from './Item.svelte';
    const indexes = [1,2,3];
    function handleClick(e) {
        const index = Number(e.target.dataset.index);
        active.set(index === $active ? 0 : index);
    }
</script>

<ul on:click={handleClick}>
    {#each indexes as index}
        <Item index={index}/>
    {/each}
</ul>
```

```js
CollapseItem.svelte:

<script>
    import { active } from './stores.js';
    export let index;
    let active_val;
    const active_unsubscribe = active.subscribe(val => active_val = val);
</script>

<style>
    .active {color: red}
</style>

<li class:active={index === active_val} data-index={index}>Number {index}</li>
```

```js
stores.js:

import { writable } from 'svelte/store';
export const active = writable();
```

Hopefully that gives you some idea of what to do!